# What can i use as a 3d Tile map editor?

Tags: 3d, tilemap, map-editor, world-editor

I need to make grid based levels with 3d models for a dungeon crawler ( as a recent example Legend of Grimrock), but i need to have several layers and place entities with properties and position, angle, etc.
I was considering Tiled, using layers as height for each level, but it's very hard to work with and visualize.
What can i use for this pourpose?
The output format needs to be json, xml, or something i can use on my engine.
Ideally i'd want something like Tiled with a 3d visualization/edit mode and support for loading models or at least some visual representation of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try TuDee:

http://www.diorgo.com/v1/?p=366

I have used it successfully for 3D tile-games. It exports XML, so it is easy to read into whatever game engine you are using. It supports multiple maps (useful for different levels), as well as layers, entities, custom variables, and many other features.

Here is some more info:

http://forums.indiegamer.com/showthread.php?28936-TuDee-a-free-tile-based-map-editor

Comment: This is still a 2D tile-editor and would have the same limitations as Tiled has... so no 3D preview or anything like that

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. What kind of visualisation do you have in mind?

Comment: i'm the op but yes, i would like some sort of 3d visualization, even if it's some sort of isometric or side view of what i'm editing, with several layers at the same time.